# IBAction in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to storyboard in ios and trying to develop an app. I have a login button and i map it to my loginsucess view on my mainsoryboard file . ( it seems when ever i am clicking login button it will push to Login success view ) . there is any way to check the condition whether credential are right  and push it to LoginSucessView .? . Normally i should create a IBAction and check the logic and push it through code . what is the best approch for storyboard. any help appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? This question has little to no information about what you have tried already. We could just be pointing you back at what you have already tried please tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

UIViewController has a handy method called `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

Within this you can perform whatever checking you want to do, and if you return YES, the segue will be performed, and if you return NO, the segue will not.

Comment: Which means that you define the segue between the view controllers but don't assign it to the button. And you will have to provide the segue with some unique ID to which you can refer as Identifier. (A string. I'd just call it "LoginSuccess".)

Answer (score 1):

// In the Attributes inspector, you fill in a seque identifier .. add seque identifier

```
   -(IBAction)BtnClickedMethods:(id)sender
   {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"loginView" sender: self];
   }   

   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginView"])
     {
        //do your checking and navigate else popup message
     }
   }
```